Community Detection with both Node and Edge Weights
I have a directed graph where there are importance or weight attributes for both the nodes and edges. I am looking for a community or module detection implementation in python that will consider both attribute types when calculating or optimizing for community detection. I know there are many python libraries like igraph, CDlib, networkx, with community detection algorithms, but I am unable to find something that clearly considers both node and edge weights. Any input or feedback on this is appreciated!

Is there a definition of what a good community detection result would be that includes node weights? Do you have that for your use case?

While not in python yet. There is the ig.degree.betweenness R package. Which implements the "Smith-Pittman" community detection algorithm which considers both node degree and edge betweenness for igraph objects.
There is a python implementation in the works however it still needs to be fully developed.

More links:
Blog about Smith-Pittman clustering: here.
Working paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2411.01394

Many clustering algorithms consider in some way the node degree. But that's something different from node weights.
